# Fibonacci iterative method - java

Tags: java

I created a method to calculate Fibonacci numbers iteratively (I'm not allowed to use recursion). After index 47 I get weird results: 

Fibonacci number 47: -1323752223

Fibonacci number 48: 512559680

Fibonacci number 49: -811192543

Fibonacci number 50: -298632863

I tried different ways, but it modifies the whole thing.
Here's my method, any ideas? Hope you can help me.

```
public static long fiboIterative(int n) {

    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    if (n == 1 || n == 2)
        return 1;

    int previous = -1;
    int result = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {

        int sum = result + previous;
        previous = result;
        result = sum;
    }

    return result;
    }
```

}

Comment: `int` are 32-bit in size and are not unlimited.  You can use `double` instead but it is also limited in terms of precision.  I suggest you try writing it to use `BigInteger` as an exercise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have overflowed the `int` used to store the current Fibonacci number.  The maximum value that can be stored in an `int` without overflow is a little over 2 billion.  [`Integer.MAX_VALUE` is `2147483647`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE).  You can use a bigger datatype, such as `long`, for `sum`, `previous`, and `result`, to print out more results.  However, it too will eventually overflow also.  [`Long.MAX_VALUE` is `9223372036854775807`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE), a little over 9 quintillion.

Comment: [integer overflow explained](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~willb/cs302/spring-07/why-integer-overflow-cl.pdf) | Try System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE); and see for yourself.

Answer (score 4):

You are running into [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow): Java's `int` type can represent numbers between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647. The 47th Fibonacci number is 2,971,215,073.

Change the type of `result`, `sum` and `previous` to `long` to expand the range to about 90 Fibonacci numbers.

If you need more, look into using [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Answer (score 3):

You're getting integer overflow.

Your result is a signed number that doesn't have the capacity to store anything beyond +`2^31`, approx.

Consider using `BigInteger` as opposed to `int` or `long`.